# Simultaneous processing of moving and rotating objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

It has a similar feeling, but this code keeps following the player.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 playerPos = _player.transform.position;
    Vector3 dirVec = playerPos - transform.position;
    dirVec = dirVec.normalized;
            
    transform.Translate(dirVec * 1f * Time.fixedDeltaTime,Space.World);
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, -Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed);   
}
```

How can I implement it only in the direction of the player and not follow it?

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

use `transorfm.lookAt()` for simple direction following:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.LookAt(_player.transform, Vector3.up);
}
```

For smooth following:

```
public float rotateTime = 1f; // must not be zero

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var dirVec = _player.transform.position - transform.position;
    
    var lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dirVec);
    
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.fixedDeltaTime/rotateTime);
}
```